# Vector end iterators

Tags: c++, stl, vector, iterator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [comparing iterators from different containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657513/comparing-iterators-from-different-containers)

In practice, `std::vector<T>::iterator` is probably implemented as a wrapped `T*` on most STL implementations, so every iterator is associated with a unique memory address (assuming the iterator comes from a non-empty vector).

However, that's an implementation detail.  Is there any actual guarantee from the C++ standard that every vector iterator is somehow unique?  Specifically, can the `end()` iterator of one non-empty vector ever equal the `end()` iterator of another non-empty vector?

For example:

```
std::vector<int> v1;
std::vector<int> v2;
/* Fill both vectors with values... */

assert(v1.end() != v2.end()); // Does C++ guarantee this assertion will succeed?
```

Answer (score 1):

Vectors can't overlap, so the end of one non-empty container cannot easily be the end of another non-empty container. The end of one vector could conceivably be equal to the end of another empty vector. But I don't think you are allowed to compare iterators into different containers, so that doesn't matter much.

Comment: It would be possible to have a special value for `end()` for every `vector` (but unlikely since the iterator could not be a raw pointer then), but like you said, it's undefined behavior to find out.