# Compare two list iterators which point to different lists

Tags: c++, list, c++03

As pointed out in other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657513/comparing-iterators-from-different-containers) here on SO, equality comparison between two iterators from different containers is UB.

In my case I have two list iterators, which might not be from the same container:

```
std::list< int >::iterator a, b;
```

Suppose that I know for sure that none of them is an end iterator, my question is if I am allowed to do:

```
&(*a) == &(*b)
```

Comment: Why not? if they are not end-iterators, dereferencing them yields an `lvalue`, whose address you surely can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can do that, as you're not comapring the iterators but the addresses of their referands.

Assuming iterators are from different containers, this comparison cannot ever be true in a well-formed program, though.

Comment: Why not? If the two iterator belong to the same container and points to the same element how can it be false?

Comment: I though you said the iterators are not from the same container?

Comment: Sorry, what I really meant was *might* be from the same container, I'll fix that.

Comment: In that case, yes, it's fine and it can be true.