# Why this code does not work as expected?

Tags: c++, list, vector, iterator

The following code does not work in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

class ListWithIterator
{
public:
    ListWithIterator() : m_iterator(m_list.end()) {}

    bool check() const { return m_iterator == m_list.end(); }

private:
    typedef std::list<int> list_t;

    list_t m_list;
    list_t::const_iterator m_iterator;
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    std::vector<ListWithIterator> v;
    v.resize(1);
    if (v[0].check())
    {
        std::cerr << "Yes" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "No" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

MSVC says:

> "Debug Assertion Failed", "Expression: list iterators incompatible" inside `check()` function.

g++ compiles it without any warnings but it works wrong:

```
$ g++ sample.cpp -g -Og -Wall
$ ./a.out
No
$
```

I expected output "Yes", because iterator was initialized by `m_list.end()` but `bool check() const { return m_iterator == m_list.end(); }` returns `false`.

**Update:**

Correct solution:

```
$ cat sample.cpp
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

class ListWithIterator
{
public:
    ListWithIterator() : m_iterator(m_list.end()) {}
    ListWithIterator(const ListWithIterator& from): m_list(from.m_list), m_iterator(m_list.end())
    {
    }

    bool check() const
    {
        std::cerr << m_list.size() << std::endl;
        return m_iterator == m_list.end();
    }

private:
    typedef std::list<int> list_t;

    list_t m_list;
    list_t::iterator m_iterator;
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    std::vector<ListWithIterator> v;
    v.resize(1);
    if (v[0].check())
    {
        std::cerr << "Yes" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "No" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
$ g++ sample.cpp -g -Og -Wall
$ ./a.out
0
Yes
$
```

Comment: I think the problem is you are comparing a `const_iterator` with `iterator` in `check()`.

Comment: Yes, it is. Put log into pastebin: http://pastebin.com/FDziGfMm

Comment: No, it does not work even if I change `const_iterator` to `iterator`.

Comment: With the new solution you lose the position of the iterator during a copy if that was important. What I mean is if the m_iterator was not pointing at the end() this is not preserved in the copy constructor.

Comment: Yes, I understand. It doesn't matter for my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are compiling without `-std=c++11` flag, and there's only one [pre-C++11 overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize):

```
void resize( size_type count, T value = T() );
```

> If the current size is less than count, additional elements are appended and initialized with copies of value.

---

Now, the defaulted copy constructor copy-constructs both member data and so you end up with an iterator to the old (destructed) list, which you later [compare with an end iterator of a different list instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657513/comparing-iterators-from-different-containers), leading to undefined behavior.

Compiling under C++11 would make the behaviour defined (an overload which uses the default constructor would be chosen), but it is in your own interest to fix the broken copy semantics.

Comment: As to Visual Studio, I am unsure of what could had (or have?) been the problem. VS2015 should have that one-parameter overload. Does it appear to work, too?

Answer (score 3):

If you're triggering the implicit copy constructor of `ListWithIterator`, then you end up with a *copy* of the list and a *copy* of the iterator. However, the copied iterator still refers to the *original* list. Comparisons of iterators for different contains is undefined.

I don't see where your `ListWithIterator` would get copied, but the message from MSVC suggests that it *is* being copied nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't defined a copy constructor, and `list::resize` inserts a copy of a default-constructed object.
This copy contains an iterator that refers to the list in the original object, not to the list in the copy.

You need to be as careful with iterators as you would be with pointers.