# Strange behaviour of std::find, returns true when the element is not in the vector

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Looks a very straight forward case, a typical use of std::find

```
for ( auto element : generic->vec() )
        LOG << element;

    LOG << channel;

    if ( !gen->vec().empty() ) {

        if(std::find(generic->vec().begin(), generic->vec().end(), channel) != generic->vec().end()){

            LOG << "Found";
            ;// Found the item
        } else {

            LOG << "Not Found";
            return false;

        }
}
```

Please check the log file

```
2018-11-08, 09:37:18 [INFO] - [140455150589696] - 1
2018-11-08, 09:37:18 [INFO] - [140455150589696] - 2
2018-11-08, 09:37:18 [INFO] - [140455150589696] - 4
2018-11-08, 09:37:18 [INFO] - [140455150589696] - 12
2018-11-08, 09:37:18 [INFO] - [140455150589696] - 40
2018-11-08, 09:37:18 [INFO] - [140455150589696] - Found
```

The vector contains 1,2,4,12 and the incoming value that we want to test if it belongs to the vector is 40. The std::find returns true, that it is found.

The vec() method returns an array of uint64_t elements:

```
std::vector<uint64_t>  vec() const {
  return vec_;
}
```

When I am creating a local vector, ie

> auto tmp = generic->vec(),

the code works.

Where is the bug in my code? I would expect to get "Not found" when checking if 40 belongs to [1,2,4,12].

Comment: the `auto tmp = generic->vec();` is a good solution

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that your `vec` function returns the vector *by value*. That means each call to `vec` will return a *different* and *distinct* vector object. And iterators from different vectors can't be compared to each other.

The simple solution is to return the vector *by reference*:

```
std::vector<uint64_t> const&  vec() const { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

The signature of `std::vector<uint64_t> vec() const` implies that an rvalue is returned (a copy of `vec_`). This is fine as long as you don't compare references to elements of `vec()` from distinct invocations. Example:

```
auto v1 = vec();
auto v2 = vec();

v1.begin() != v2.begin(); // Don't do that - UB
```

This is the same as

```
vec().begin() != vec().begin(); // Again, UB
```

Thanks to @Aconcagua for pointing out that the comparison is undefined behavior in the first place, see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4657513/9593596).

Such things can be hard to spot when you're used to range based for loops, e.g.

```
for (const auto& value : vec()) { /* ... */ }
```

That's not a problem, but under the hood, this snippet is expanded such that the return value of `vec()` is bound to a `auto&&` variable and any calls to `*begin/*end` methods refer to the same object.

Long story short: bind the return value to a variable before requesting iterators or change the signature ov `vec()` such that it returns a reference, not a copy.

Comment: Actually, you are already invoking undefined behaviour by comparing iterators from distinct vectors against each other...

Comment: @Aconcagua Good hint, I wasn't aware that it's UB! I'll edit.