# Why apply a non-exist key to map::find would return a iterator with first value map size in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have a use case like the code snippet below, using `map::find` in a getter returned map to find a non-exist key would actually find a iterator which first value is the size of the map (likely), thus would not behave as expect, equals with `map::end`

this is probably because of my map was a getter returned map. And consumed the map without assign it to a variable. So that the getter returned value may have been destructed immediately.

1. So if my guess is correct?
2. Why it returned the size of the map instead of its end iterator?

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <map>


    class B {
        long long id_;

        public:
        B() = default;
        explicit B(long long);
        ~B() = default;
    };

    B::B(long long int id) : id_(id) {}


    class A {
        std::string id_;
        std::map<long long, std::shared_ptr<B>> b_;

        public:
        A() = default;
        explicit A(std::string id);
        ~A() = default;

        const std::string &id() const;

        std::map<long long, std::shared_ptr<B>> b();

    };

    A::A(std::string id): id_(id) {
        b_[1] = std::make_shared<B>(1);
        b_[2] = std::make_shared<B>(2);
    }

    const std::string &A::id() const {
        return id_;
    }

    std::map<long long, std::shared_ptr<B>> A::b() {
        return b_;
    }


    int main() {
        std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>("arst");
        if (a->b().find(3) != a->b().end()) {
            std::cout << a->b().find(3)->first << std::endl;
            std::cout << a->b().at(3) << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

run as below:

```sh
clang --version
```

```sh
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

with output:

```sh
clang++ test.cc -std=c++11
./a.out
```

```sh
2
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: map::at:  key not found
[1]    64348 abort      ./a.out
```

Comment: I think it's safe to say, that given `A::id()` that returns by reference, you probably just made a typo.

Comment: @StoryTeller it was not a typo, but a mistake. Now I learned the right way to do it- -

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
std::map<long long, std::shared_ptr<B>> A::b();
```

You are returning the `map` by value, so each time you call `a->b()` you create a new copy of the map `b_` which is why this kind of comparison:

```
a->b().find(3) != a->b().end()
```

...is *undefined behavior* since each call to `b()` returns a different map and [comparing iterators from different container is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4664519/5470596).

Change your declaration (and definition) to return a (`const`-)reference:

```
const std::map<long long, std::shared_ptr<B>>& A::b();
```

Answer (score 9):

Your function `A::b()` returns the map *by value*. That means a *copy* is returned, a *unique* copy each time it is called, and whose iterators are *not* compatible with the iterators from any other copy.

Return *by reference* instead.